# Storing text file in Oracle DB as BLOB cuts off the end of the file

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I'm generating a text file in a process which at the end loops through a list of strings that were fed to it, and through a `MemoryStream` and `StreamWriter` it converts that list to `byte[]`. The `byte[]` is then saved to an Oracle Database using a `BLOB` datatype. While it works for the majority of the data (typically thousands of lines. I've had anywhere between 5,000 and 40,000, and it's the same result regardless), I have a specific `message` that goes at the end, but it's always missing. Generally the last line that does end up in the file is cut off halfway.

The function that generates the `byte[]`:

```
public byte[] GenerateFileData()
{
    var fileData = new byte[0];

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
        {
            Messages.ForEach(x => sw.WriteLine(x)); // Messages is a list of strings in this class
            fileData = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return fileData;
}
```

The function that saves the `byte[]` to the database:

```
public void SaveLogFile(int entityId, byte[] fileData)
{
    using (var context = new SomeDBContext())
    {
        var entity= context.SomeEntity.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == runId);
        if(entity != null)
        {
            entity.LOG_FILE = fileData;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly, the function that turns the data into a file:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetLogFile(int id = 0)
{
    var fileData = new byte[0];

    using (var context = new SomeDbContext())
    {
        var entity = context.SomeEntity.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        fileData = entity.LOG_FILE;
    }

    var fileName = "SomethingSomething" + id.ToString();

    return File(fileData, "text/plain", fileName);
}
```

Comment: Try to generate `byte[]` like this --> `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Messages));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get the MemoryStream content after the writer close asthis code:

```
public byte[] GenerateFileData()
{
    var fileData = new byte[0];

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
        {
            Messages.ForEach(x => sw.WriteLine(x)); // Messages is a list of strings in this class
        }
        ms.Flush();
        fileData = ms.ToArray();
    }

    return fileData;
}
```

Comment: When `sw` is disposed, it will flush `sw` and then flush its underlying stream (`ms`), so there's no need to call `ms.Flush()` explicitly after that using block.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. I don't suppose you could add some more detail as to why this works for anybody looking this up in the future?